# SQL to sort the data on multiple columns and add a column to assign an incremental counter for each sort combination

Tags: sql-server

I have this as input data

```
CustomerId   Customer_name  PurchaseId Purchase_Date
----------------------------------------------------     
1234         Robert Benson  ABC123      12/07/2012
1218         Gary Thomas    PP122       26/01/2013
1218         Gary Thomas    PP122       28/01/2013
1234         Robert Benson  ABC123      28/01/2013
1234         Robert Benson  ABC123      29/01/2013
1254         Robert Sharma  PML563      29/04/2012
1218         Gary Thomas    PR124       06/03/2013
1234         Benson Cruiso  LML123      14/07/2012
1234         Martha Cruiso  FMPL123     15/07/2012
```

I want to sort the data on multiple columns i.e `CustomerId` and `PurchaseId` and add an order of the sorted data as

```
GroupID  CustomerId   Customer_name  PurchaseId Purchase_Date
-------------------------------------------------------------      
1       1218            Gary Thomas    PR124       06/03/2013
1       1218            Gary Thomas    PP122       26/01/2013
2       1218            Gary Thomas    PP122       28/01/2013
1       1234            Robert Benson  ABC123      12/07/2012
2       1234            Robert Benson  ABC123      28/01/2013
2       1234            Robert Benson  PP122       29/01/2013
1       1234            Benson Cruiso  LML123      14/07/2012
1       1234            Martha Cruiso  FMPL123     15/07/2012
1       1254            Robert Sharma  PML563      27/04/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be achieved with a simple `row_number` or `rank`, depending on how you want your query to handle ties.

```
Select Row_Number() over 
                   (partition by CustomerID, PurchaseID 
                    order by PurchaseDate) as GroupID, *
from MyTable
```

This will assign sequential numbers to rows that have the same `CustomerID` and `PurchaseID`, assigning 1 to the first `PurchaseDate`, 2 to the next, and so on, and starting the numbering over again when it reaches a new `CustomerID`/`PurchaseID` combination.  In the event of two rows with the same `CustomerID`, `PurchaseID`, and `PurchaseDate`, it will arbitrarily assign different numbers.  If you want those cases to be treated as ties and assigned the same number, use `rank` or `dense_rank` instead of `row_number.`